# mockjax response not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mockjax

I have some little problem with understanding mockjax. I have this mockjax code:

```
$.mockjax({
  url: "get_image.php",
  responseText:{
    hello: 'world'
  }  
});
```

What should be js code to alert 'world'? Maybe this?

```
$.getJson("url" , function(){
  alert(response.hello)
});
```

But this is not working, please help me!

Comment: Probably the response is undefined, I think should be `function(response)`

Comment: should it be like this

`$.getJson("get_image.php" , function(response){
  alert(response.hello)
});`

Comment: i don't know , but this is steal not working.

Comment: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined(…)

Comment: Mb the problem in mockjax code?
Pls check it , but i think this is correctly

Comment: or mb u can write your personal code of this elementary example?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add argument `response` in function.

```
$.getJson("url" , function(response){
  alert(response.hello);
});
```

[Read more about `getJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: this is steal not working, response.hello os undefinded , maybe the error in mockjax code, can u check it?
But i think this is correctly

Comment: Can you please update question with value of `response` ? It says it element `hello` not found in `response`.